# 7zip is nowhere to be found

Tags: 7zip

I just installed 7zip from the Ubuntu Software Centre, but when I look for it in my applications, I can't find it. Even when I type "7z" in the terminal, it is telling me that 7zip is installed. How can I find the application and open it up? Thank you.

Comment: 7z doesn't provide a GUI on Ubuntu. Use the Archive Manager (`file-roller`) program instead.,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I find the application and open it up?

On the desktop": the application you want is "archive manager". On our system all archive programs get attached to this programs and when an archiver/unarchiver is available "archive manager" recognizes it and lets you use it. Example images, "7z" selected from the drop down.

[image]

Command line you can use "7z" yourself manually too. `man 7z` will show a description and `7z --help` the options.

```
$7z --help

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)

Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
       [<@listfiles...>]

<Commands>
  a: Add files to archive
  b: Benchmark
  d: Delete files from archive
  e: Extract files from archive (without using directory names)
  l: List contents of archive
  t: Test integrity of archive
  u: Update files to archive
  x: eXtract files with full paths
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own launcher to run it. The launcher command for it  is :

```
/usr/bin/Q7Z.pyw
```